# Erro E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical. Como Solucionar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou tentando escrever um procedure em Delphi 10. 
A procedure chama um form que uso para aprestar mensagens de erro. Mas quando tento fazer a coias funcionar, o Delphi dá um erro como:

> ```
> [dcc32 Error] UntPrincipal.pas(6318): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
> ```

Minha procedure

```
...
  public
       procedure ChamaMsg(var TipoMsg: Integer; TextMeg: string);
  end;
...
procedure TfrmPrincipal.ChamaMsg(var TipoMsg: Integer; TextMeg: string);
begin
  IMsg := TipoMsg;
  if frmSplash = nil then
    Application.CreateForm(TfrmSplash, frmSplash);

  frmSplash.SplashText.Caption := TextMeg;
  frmSplash.ShowModal;

  FreeAndNil(frmSplash);
end;
```

Como eu chamo a Procedure:

```
// vMsg eu monto o texto para exibir na telinha da mensagem. 
vMsg  := 'Este Item ('+IntToStr(DMR.Produtos_ID_PRODUTO.AsInteger)+') não está presente neste Pedido!'+#13+#13+#13+'(Esc) Para Sair.';

ChamaMsg(1, vMsg);
```

Qual pode ser a solução para esse erro ... Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Na declaração do procedimento você utilizou `var TipoMsg: Integer`
Sendo assim o delphi identifica o `TipoMsg` como um ponteiro/referência na memória.

Isto possibilita que dentro do procedimento você possa reescrever o conteúdo do parâmetro `TipoMsg` para que quem o chamou possa receber um valor diferente do que enviou.

Portanto, você não pode utilizar:

```
ChamaMsg(1, vMsg);
```

Pois 1 não pode ser considerado um ponteiro/referência.

Tente utilizar

```
var
  vValor: Integer;
begin
  vValor := 1;
  ChamaMsg(vValor, vMsg);

  // dentro do procedimento é possível reescrever o valor do parâmetro  

  if vValor <> 1 then
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Opa!!!
Beleza, vou tentar fazer como está na sua explicação.